# Update part of linear indices in 1D Tensor

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, tensorflow, data-science

I want to update only part of linear indices (in ones_flat), for example, half or quarter, like that: [0,1,2,3,.....N] changed to [0,1,....,N/2]

```
    temp_var = tf.get_variable("W")
    size_2a = tf.get_variable("b")
    s1 = tf.shape(temp_var).eval()[0]
    s2 = tf.shape(size_2a).eval()[0]

    ones_mask = tf.ones([s1,s2])
    indices = tf.slice(ones_mask,[0,0],[s1/2,s2])
    # turn into 1d variable since "scatter_update" supports linear indexing only
    ones_flat = tf.Variable(tf.reshape(ones_mask, [-1]))
    indices_flat = tf.Variable(tf.reshape(indices, [-1]))

    # get linear indices
    linear_indices = tf.random_uniform(tf.shape(indices_flat), dtype=tf.int32, minval=0, maxval =s1*s2)

    # no automatic promotion, so make updates float32 to match ones_mask
    updates = tf.zeros(shape=(tf.shape(linear_indices)), dtype=tf.float32)
    ones_flat_new = tf.scatter_update(ones_flat,linear_indices, updates) 

    # convert back into original shape
    ones_mask_new = tf.reshape(ones_flat_new, ones_mask.get_shape())

    W.assign(tf.mul(ones_mask_new,W))
```

The thing is, after setting to zero 1/2 of elements in ones_mask and multiplication to W, W doesn't seem to change, since the accuracy of the network doesn't change. And there's no mistakes, just this:

```
Accuracy_old: 0.9113
Extracting /tmp/data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Extracting /tmp/data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
lin_ind Tensor("foo_1/random_uniform:0", shape=(1960,), dtype=int32)
upd Tensor("foo_1/zeros:0", shape=(3920,), dtype=float32)
W Tensor("foo/W/read:0", shape=(784, 10), dtype=float32)
Accuracy_new: 0.9113
```

Can you please help me to find the mistake here?

Comment: Sorry, could you possibly make a rephrase your question in a more focused example of what you would like to test?

Comment: @drpng, of course, excuse me.
I want to check whether is my scatter_update is working correctly.
It is a problem, because I can get only info about the shape of the matrices, since I didn't find a way how to print it like [[1,0,1,...,1],[0,1,1,..,0]], etc (eval() didn't help) 
So I have no mistakes shown in the log,  and no changes in accuracy, which depends on the prediction: `pred = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)`

Comment: I see. You should be able to do `get_shape().shape` and print it.

Comment: @drpng, thanks, but I already know the shape (checked it), it's (7840,)
I need to know the exact values of ones_flat_new in order to understand, were weights really set to zero or not. Or a way to check it somehow else.

Comment: You can do `print(sess.run(ones_flat_new))`, if you want a "pretty print", you can also do `ones_flat_new = tf.Print(ones_flat_new, [ones_flat_new], "Ones flat new:")`.

Comment: @drpng, thank you, I checked evrything and discovered that update works perfectly well, and the problem is in the other place.